# MySQL Query optimization with JOIN and COUNT

Tags: mysql, file, sorting

I have the following MySQL Query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.releaseid, t1.site, t1.date, t2.pos FROM `tracers` as t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `releaseid`, `date`, COUNT(*) AS `pos` 
    FROM `tracers` GROUP BY `releaseid`
) AS t2 ON t1.releaseid = t2.releaseid AND t2.date <= t1.date 
ORDER BY `date` DESC , `pos` DESC LIMIT 0 , 100
```

The idea being to select a release and count how many other sites had also released it prior to the recorded date, to get the position.

Explain says:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY t1  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    498422  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    91661    
2   DERIVED tracers index   NULL    releaseid   4   NULL    498422
```

Any suggestions on how to eliminate the Using temporary; Using filesort ?  It takes a loooong time. The indexes I have thought of and tried haven't helped anything.

Comment: what are your exact indices? `(releaseid)`, `(releaseid, date)` and `(date, pos)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index on `tracers.releaseid` and one on `tracers.date`

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have an index on releaseid.
2. flip your JOIN, the sub-query must be on the left side in the LEFT JOIN.
3. put the ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses inside the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Try having two indices, one on `(date)` and one on `(releaseid, date)`.

Another thing is that your query does not seem to be doing what you describe it does. Does it actually count correctly?

Try rewriting it as:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.releaseid, t1.site, t1.`date`
     , COUNT(*) AS pos
FROM tracers AS t1
  JOIN tracers AS t2
    ON  t2.releaseid = t1.releaseid
    AND t2.`date` <= t1.`date` 
GROUP BY t1.releaseid
ORDER BY t1.`date` DESC
       , pos DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

or as:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.releaseid, t1.site, t1.`date`
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM tracers AS t2
         WHERE t2.releaseid = t1.releaseid
           AND t2.`date` <= t1.`date`
       ) AS pos
FROM tracers AS t1
ORDER BY t1.`date` DESC
       , pos DESC
LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer below maybe not change explain output, however if your major problem is sorting data, which it identified by **removing order clause will makes your query run faster**, try to sort your subquery join table first and your query will be:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.releaseid, t1.site, t1.date, t2.pos FROM `tracers` as t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `releaseid`, `date`, COUNT(*) AS `pos` 
    FROM `tracers` GROUP BY `releaseid`
    ORDER BY `pos` DESC -- additional order
) AS t2 ON t1.releaseid = t2.releaseid AND t2.date <= t1.date 
ORDER BY `date` DESC , `pos` DESC LIMIT 0 , 100
```

Note: My db version is mysql-5.0.96-x64, maybe in another version you get different result.